# Show that $f^{-1}(B)=A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I started yesterday my study of functions. I’m following the book *“Proofs and Fundamentals”*, by Ethan D. Bloch, and I’m having some trouble in starting myself in formal proofs that involve functions. This is one of my problems.

**Problem:**

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and $f \colon A \to B$ be a function. Show that $f^{-1}(B) = A$.

So far, I understand that I will have to show that $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$. The only definition that I have used is that of a function given by Bloch as a subset of $A \times B$.

So, **my proof** was something like this.

> By definition, $f^{-1}(B) = \{a \in A \mid \exists b \in B: f(a) = b\}$. Let $x \in f^{-1}(B)$. Then $x \in A$ and it exists some $b \in B$ such that $f(x) = b$. In particular, $x \in A$. Hence, $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq A$.
>
> Now, let $a \in A$. Since $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, there exists a unique ordered pair of the form $(x,y)$ for all $x \in A$ and some $y \in B$ with $y = f(x)$. So, there must be a unique ordered pair $(a,b)$ with $b \in B$ and $b = f(a)$. For that, $f(a) \in B$; and by definition, $a \in f^{-1}(B)$. Hence, $A \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$.
>
> Therefore, we have that $f^{-1}(B)=A$. $\square$

Please give all the feedback to turn this proof as formal as possible.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is a correct proof.

Comment: Your proof is fine. To make things more concise you could also go for definition: $f^{-1}(B):=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in B\}$. Then the second part is actually not more than this. "Let $a\in A. Then - because $f$ is a function with codomain $B$ - we have $f(a)\in B$ so we are ready."

Comment: @Berci thank you for the comment!

Comment: @drhab thank you for the comment! The advice was really helpful and I think it was useful to turn my proof more simple and concise

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the statement of the problem is correct, unless you tacitly assume that $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $B$ is the range of $f$. Here's an easy counterexample:

Let $f(x) = x^2$. Then $f([0,\infty)) = [0,\infty)$, but $f^{-1}([0,\infty)) = (-\infty,\infty)$.

Here are some modifications of the problem that would make it correct:

(1) Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f:A\to B$ be a **bijective** function. Show that $f^{-1}(B) = A$.

(2) Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f:A\to B$ **so that $f$ is only defined on $A$**. Show that $f^{-1}(B) = A$.

(3) Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f:A\to B$ be a function. Show that $A\subset f^{-1}(B)$.

This is how I would write this proof:

> Let $a\in A$. Then $f(a) = b\in B$ from the given, hence, $a\in f^{-1}(b)$. This shows that $A\subset f^{-1}(B)$. (This would finish
> the proof for (3)).
>
> Let $b\in B$ and assume $f^{-1}(b)$ is defined and $f^{-1}(b) = x\notin A$.
>
> (2) But then $f(x) = b$, which contradicts the assumption that $f$ is only defined on $A$, hence, $A\supset f^{-1}(B)$ and we're done.
>
> (1) Since $f$ is surjective,
> there must be some $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. But that means that
> $f(a) = f(x)$ with $a\neq x$, which contradicts injectivity of $f$.
> Hence, $A\supset f^{-1}(B)$ and we're done.

Comment: If you write $f:A\to B$, then $f$ is only defined on $A$. So your assumption (2) always holds.

Comment: Your counterexample only works as a function $f\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$. If one defines $f$ as a function $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, there is no problem. (note that $f(-1)$ is not even defined then!)

Comment: ok, I see. Stefan or Kenta (or someone else), is the protocol to remove my answer or to edit it? Also I note that this question is 1 year old and was just recently edited... not sure Air Mike would even read this.

Comment: @MishaShklyar When I say that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, that means that the domain of $f$ is the set $A$. Also $B$ is not the range of $f$, it is the codomain of $f$, which may be different